# Can't parse JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse the following JSON response:

```
{
  "AgApplyTableE*!": [
    {
      "Index": 1,
      "StringVal": "Error: Enabled virtual server 3 has no IP address.U+0085Error: Apply not done.  Use 'diff' to see pending changes,U+0085 then use configuration menus to correct errors.U+0085"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
$('#applyfailreason').click(function (){    
  var t = $(this);
  var DeviceName = $('.DeviceName').val();
  var Username = $('.Username').val();
  var Password = $('.Password').val();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://' + DeviceName + '/config/AgApplyTable',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('' + Username + '' + ":" + '' + Password + '')
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      var test = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(test);
    },
    statusCode: {
      406 : function() {
        alert('There is an unexpected string in your data.\nFix the error and try again.');
      },
      401 : function() {
        alert('Wrong username or password.');
      }
    },
  });                   
});
```

I get the following on the console (which is ok):

```
{"AgApplyTableE*!":[{"Index":1,"StringVal":"Error: Enabled virtual server 3 has no IP address.U+0085Error: Apply not done.  Use 'diff' to see pending changes,U+0085       then use configuration menus to correct errors.U+0085"}]}
```

But I want to print only the "StringVal" out of the JSON response.
Tried:

```
var test2 = JSON.stringify(data.StringVal);
console.log(test2);
```

Gives:

```
undefined
```

I also tried the following (with `dataType: 'jsonp',`):

```
var test4 = JSON.parse(data.StringVal);
```

But then Chrome sends a GET request to a strange URI (which actually gives 200OK):

```
config/AgApplyTable?callback=jQuery111306132095118518919_1436256387242&_=1436256387244
```

And I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any idea how to print to console only "StringVal" out of the JSON response?

Thanks.

Comment: `var test4 = JSON.parse(data.AgApplyTableE*![0][StringVal]);`

Comment: Have you tried this `var test2 = JSON.stringify(data["AgApplyTableE*!"][0].StringVal);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log(data['AgApplyTableE*!'][0].StringVal)`

In your response, there is no such thing as `StringVal` as direct suboridnate of data. The property `StringVal` is inside the internal object `AgApplyTableE*!` therefore data.StringVal is undefined.

Also, another problem I see here is that you're `stringify`ing the response and then trying to access the property `StringVal`.
If you `stringify`, you `test` variable will be a string and string doesnt have a property `StringVal` (unless you set that in your proto)

EDIT:
Added missing `[0]` index.

Comment: That is incorrect. "AgApplyTableE*!" is an array containing one object.

Comment: @Maverick
Your code works for me.
Thanks a lot!
And thank you everybody for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Your response is an object containing one property named "AgApplyTableE*!", which is an array that contains one element, which is an object that contains the property "StringVal".

So you'd have to access it by `data["AgApplyTableE*!"][0].StringVal`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var test2 = data["AgApplyTableE*!"][0].StringVal;
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you have two levels here, not only one. In order to get that value out, you probably would need something like

```
var test2 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(test2["AgApplyTableE*!"][0].StringVal);
```

Altough I'm not sure AgApplyTableE*! is a really good identifier here. Probably you can change something else, and then you can also use . notation to reach the members.

Comment: Remove the dot operator after test2: `test2["AgApplyTableE*!"]`

Comment: Your code never work with JSON.stringify. test2 is not an object but a json in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your fix R3tep . You're right, I copied the wrong line. Fixed to be JSON.parse as it should be.

Comment: I would really prefer people to actually test their post instead of editing it later by half of its code changed. Would spare everyone some time :)

Comment: Sure. But when you think it's simple, and you have the correct answer for sure, you just write it down, try to save some time for yourself. I was in a hurry, still tried to help, and made a mistake in the copy-paste. I'm not perfect. It happens with everybody sometimes. I accepted the fix and edited my post, so the next time someone see it, see the correct solution, and do not have to waste his time go through the comments for the good solution.

Comment: So remove `Json.parse`. The `dataType` is setted to json, so the Ajax return is already a javascript object [see the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). And @Lain test your code before speaking, you have the same error in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
test ={"AgApplyTableE*!":[{"Index":1,"StringVal":"Error: Enabled virtual server 3 has no IP address.U+0085Error: Apply not done.  Use 'diff' to see pending changes,U+0085       then use configuration menus to correct errors.U+0085"}]};

console.log(test["AgApplyTableE*!"][0]["StringVal"]);
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d59g0rc4/)**